# MVC4 Html.BeginForm submit button in internet Explorer >9 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, postback, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a form written in ASP.NET MVC4/Razor. The form post works perfectly well in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason in Internet Explorer 10 and 11, the "Submit" button is unresponsive. (Internet Explorer 9 works also good).

This is how my form in the view looks like:

```
<div class="bla">
    <table style="width:100%;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController", FormMethod.Post, new        {id="myID"}))
    {
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="heading highlight">Enter Registration</th>
                <th>
                    <span style="display: block;">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sign)
                        <input style="margin-left:4px;" type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </span>
                    <span style="display: block; font-weight: normal;">@(Model.SignDescription)</span>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(InfoModel infoModel)
{
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoModel.Sign))
     {
            //do something
     }

     infoModel = LoadModel ();

     return (indoModel);
}
```

I really have no idea why this is happening...

THanks in Advance!

EDIT:
My form is inside a table, I forgot to add it..

Comment: Most likely due to the invalid HTML this would render. Your browser's probably in quirks mode.

Comment: @TiesonT.: How about pointing out the invalid html.

Comment: `<form><thead> ... </head></form>`

Comment: Im working in DOcument Mode : Edge (Default) according to the Menu F12 Develop tool..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is invalid - form element cannot be child of table element. Rearrange your markup so `@using (Html.BeginForm(` will be inside `<th>` .

Comment: Yes!! that´s was the problem!... Thanks A lot to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to Write 'Mycontroller' complete try writing with prefix only in form.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that your users haven't disabled JavaScript.
I spent the last 2 days trying to work out why this didn't work on IE8, but was fine on other browsers. I even had to build a windows XP hyper-v installation, just to try and reproduce the issue!