# Mvc controller method call from view button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call Controller method from a Button in view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DownloadTemplate()
{       
    return View("DownloadTemplate");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult onclick()
{
    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<td class="rightalign">
   <span class="leftalign">                               
        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
          .Name("btnBlankTemplate")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
          .Content("Blank Template"))
   </span>
```

How can i Simply call the `onclick()` method by clicking the view button?

If Kendo MVC is not supporting how can I use simple Button?

Comment: you can use javascript for this

Comment: Is this a [MVC form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077308/mvc4-html-beginform-submit-button-in-internet-explorer-9-not-working) that is filled out. The methods in your controller that have a corresponding view are called actions and can be [called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753779/mvc-button-click-to-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added  below and it is working.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BlankTemplate()
{
    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
    return View();
}
```

view :

```
<script>
    BlankTemplate = function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: _rootUrl + "Controller/BlankTemplate",
                data: {                   
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
        }
</script>

<span class="leftalign">
<input type="button" id="btnBlankTemplate" class="k-button" value="Blank Template" onclick="BlankTemplate();" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below should work.

```
                         @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                         .Name("btnBlankTemplate")
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
                         .Content("Blank Template"))
                         .onclick(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

refer to the kendo ui documentation here

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/button/events

Comment: I am using the Events. And giving the Url in JavaScript. Still not working. can you let me know what to include in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Ajax and simply pass the value using Html.beginform().

```
controller:

public ActionResult DownloadTemplate()
{
  //To Do
}

View:
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadTemplate", "Controller", FormMethod.Post}))
    {
       <span class="leftalign">
       <input type="submit" id="btnBlankTemplate" class="k-button" value="Blank Template"/>
      </span>
    }
```